# scientific measurements +- error in Rmarkdown/bookdown tables

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

What would be the best way to get a good table (with `kable`, for example) if I want to have a measurement and its error in the form `y +- error` or `y(error)`, having the usual rules for error: have 1 significant digit in error, the same number of digits in value, and so on. For instance:

- 1.124 \pm 0.003
- 0.30 \pm 0.02

and so on.

## Reproducible example

```
df<-data.frame(
  x=runif(5),
  Delta.x=runif(5)/10,
  y=runif(5),
  Delta.y=runif(5)/7
)
df.print<-with(df, data.frame(
  x=paste0(x, "(", Delta.x, ")"),
  y=paste0(y, "(", Delta.y, ")")
))

kable(df.print)
```

If I use `format(x, digits=3)` x, y and their Deltas, I get different "widths", and I would like to get the same number of digits after the decimal point.

Comment: You could use `sprintf`: `df.print<-with(df, data.frame(
  x=paste(sprintf("%.2f", x), "±", sprintf("%.2f", Delta.x)),
  y=paste(sprintf("%.2f", y), "±", sprintf("%.2f", Delta.y))
))`

Comment: Would there be a way to choose the number of digits (`"%.2f"`, `"%.3f"`) automatically based on Delta.x or Delta.y values?

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27767841/2572423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` take on your problem, which is arguably very verbose. Some explanations:

1) The first `mutate()` block rounds both `Delta` columns to have one significant digit and transforms it to a character; this preserves the length.

2) The second `mutate()` block rounds the "normal" `x` and `y` columns to have the same length as the `Delta` columns. The `- 2L` avoids false rounding based on the number before the `.` and the `.` itself in the `Delta` columns.

3) The third `mutate()` block first takes care of two "unusual" situations: the first `if_else()` takes care of situations where the rounded `y` number does not have a `.` and digits, but the `Delta.y` value does. The second `if_else()` takes care of situations where the last digit in the rounding process is a `0`, which `R` drops in rounding. Both measures are repeated for the `x` column.

4) The fourth `mutate()` block adds white space at the end of the values in the `x` and `y` columns to make sure the error numbers are aligned.

5) The `unite()` and `mutate()` commands at the end merge the columns and add parantheses for the second number.

```
library("tidyverse")
library("knitr")

df %>% 
  mutate(Delta.x = signif(Delta.x, digits = 1L), 
         Delta.x = as.character(Delta.x), 
         Delta.y = signif(Delta.y, digits = 1L), 
         Delta.y = as.character(Delta.y)) %>% 
  mutate(x = round(x, digits = str_count(Delta.x) - 2L), 
         x = as.character(x),
         y = round(y, digits = str_count(Delta.y) - 2L), 
         y = as.character(y)) %>% 
  mutate(y = if_else(condition = str_count(y, "\\.") == 0, 
                     true = str_c(y, str_dup("0", str_count(Delta.y) - str_count(y) - 1L), sep = "."),
                     false = y),
         y = if_else(condition = str_count(Delta.y) - str_count(y) != 0,
                     true = str_c(y, str_dup("0", times = str_count(Delta.y) - str_count(y))),
                     false = y),
         x = if_else(condition = str_count(x, "\\.") == 0, 
                     true = str_c(x, str_dup("0", str_count(Delta.x) - str_count(x) - 1L), sep = "."),
                     false = x),
         x = if_else(condition = str_count(Delta.x) - str_count(x) != 0,
                     true = str_c(x, str_dup("0", times = str_count(Delta.x) - str_count(x))),
                     false = x)) %>% 
  mutate(x = if_else(condition = str_count(x) < max(str_count(x)),
                     true = str_c(x, str_dup(" ", times = max(str_count(x)) - str_count(x))),
                     false = x),
         y = if_else(condition = str_count(y) < max(str_count(y)),
                     true = str_c(y, str_dup(" ", times = max(str_count(y)) - str_count(y))),
                     false = y)) %>%
  unite(x, x, Delta.x, sep = " (") %>% 
  unite(y, y, Delta.y, sep = " (") %>% 
  mutate(x = str_c(x, ")"), 
         y = str_c(y, ")")) %>% 
  kable()


|x           |y             |
|:-----------|:-------------|
|1.0  (0.1)  |0.20  (0.01)  |
|0.12 (0.07) |0.8   (0.1)   |
|0.71 (0.03) |0.18  (0.09)  |
|0.63 (0.02) |0.805 (0.003) |
|0.27 (0.09) |0.106 (0.008) |
```

Additionally, you can set the global `options(scipen = 999)` (or any other large number) to avoid scientific representation of numbers, e.g. `2e-5` (which in the case of your `kable` should look like `0.00002`).

**EDIT**: Updated and clarified some of the commands.

## UPDATE (Javi_VM)

I just turned it into a function. You can give either 2 vectors or 1 data.frame with two columns. It still lacks support for scientific notation (1.05 10^9 for example) but it is ok to start.

```
scinumber <- function(df=NULL, x, Delta.x){
  if (is.null(df)) {
    df <- data.frame(
      x = x,
      Delta.x = Delta.x
    )
  } else {
    colnames(df)[colnames(df)==x] <- "x"
    colnames(df)[colnames(df)==Delta.x] <- "Delta.x"
  }
  require(tidyverse)
  options(scipen = 999)
  output <- 
    df %>% 
    mutate(Delta.x = signif(Delta.x, digits = 1L), 
           Delta.x = as.character(Delta.x)) %>% 
    mutate(x = round(x, digits = str_count(Delta.x) - 2L), 
           x = as.character(x)
    ) %>% 
    mutate(x = if_else(condition = str_count(x, "\\.") == 0, 
                       true = str_c(x, str_dup("0", str_count(Delta.x) - str_count(x) - 1L), sep = "."),
                       false = x),
           x = if_else(condition = str_count(Delta.x) - str_count(x) != 0,
                       true = str_c(x, str_dup("0", times = str_count(Delta.x) - str_count(x))),
                       false = x)) %>% 
    mutate(x = if_else(condition = str_count(x) < max(str_count(x)),
                       true = str_c(x, str_dup(" ", times = max(str_count(x)) - str_count(x))),
                       false = x)) %>%
    unite(x, x, Delta.x, sep = " (") %>% 
    mutate(x = str_c(x, ")"))

  return(output)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer however has two problems. First I do not understand it (I guess I should take a look to `tidiverse`). Second, I still have the problem getting the number of digits automatically so that the uncertainty always has only one significant digit

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question initially; I've updated my answer accordingly, which should now dynamically produce the output you desire. Let me know if this was what you were looking for!

Comment: Thank you so much for your edit, @Supertasty. One thing still remains, to convert this to a function to use it more easily, but I won't ask that of you, I'll try to do it by myself. Thank you again!! I'll make further tests to check it will work in all cases...