# How do I add two character variables that are structured as timestamps in R and return a character output?

Tags: r, for-loop, time

I am attempting to add together two "timestamps" in R. I say timestamps in quotations because they are character variables and are not technically times. The data in the `ExtractionTime` column is the minute/second point of a video and the data in the `PropertyTime` column is the timestamp at the point of the video that needs to be cut. I ideally want to add `ExtractionTime` and `PropertyTime` and then return their sum in the `ClipTime` column. I have created code that does just this but it does not add minutes once the code hits 59 seconds. Any idea of how to do this? Thanks!

Here is some of my data:

```
ExtractionTime
<chr>
PropertyTime
<chr>
ClipTime
<lgl>
00:16:49    10:00:13    NA      
00:16:50    10:00:13    NA      
00:16:51    10:00:13    NA      
00:16:52    10:00:13    NA      
00:16:53    10:00:13    NA      
00:16:54    10:00:13    NA
```

Here is my code:

```
time.combine=function(x, y)
  for (i in seq_len(length(x))) {
    first.ex<-as.numeric(sub("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", "\\1", x))
    second.ex<-as.numeric(sub("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", "\\2", x))
    third.ex<-as.numeric(sub("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", "\\3", x))
    first.prop<-as.numeric(sub("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", "\\1", y))
    second.prop<-as.numeric(sub("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", "\\2", y))
    third.prop<-as.numeric(sub("(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)", "\\3", y))
    
    first<-first.ex+first.prop
    second<-second.ex+second.prop
    third<-third.ex+third.prop

 combined.times<-paste(first,second,third, sep = ":")
    return(combined.times)
  }

test.df$ClipTime<-time.combine(test.df$ExtractionTime, test.df$PropertyTime)
```

Which results in...

```
ExtractionTime
<chr>
PropertyTime
<chr>
ClipTime
<chr>
00:16:49    10:00:13    10:16:62        
00:16:50    10:00:13    10:16:63        
00:16:51    10:00:13    10:16:64        
00:16:52    10:00:13    10:16:65        
00:16:53    10:00:13    10:16:66        
00:16:54    10:00:13    10:16:67
```

But what I want is...

```
ExtractionTime
<chr>
PropertyTime
<chr>
ClipTime
<chr>
00:16:49    10:00:13    10:17:02        
00:16:50    10:00:13    10:17:03        
00:16:51    10:00:13    10:17:04        
00:16:52    10:00:13    10:17:05        
00:16:53    10:00:13    10:17:06        
00:16:54    10:00:13    10:17:07
```

How can I get this data instead?

Comment: [Convert hour:minute:second (HH:MM:SS) string to proper time class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034424/convert-hourminutesecond-hhmmss-string-to-proper-time-class) to easily perform arithmetics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write it down simple like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df = tribble(
  ~ExtractionTime, ~PropertyTime,
  "00:16:49", "10:00:13", 
  "00:16:50", "10:00:13", 
  "00:16:51", "10:00:13", 
  "00:16:52", "10:00:13", 
  "00:16:53", "10:00:13", 
  "00:16:54", "10:00:13", 
)

df %>% mutate(
  ExtractionTime = ExtractionTime %>% hms() %>% as.duration(),
  PropertyTime = PropertyTime %>% hms() %>% as.duration(),
  ClipTime = (ExtractionTime + PropertyTime) %>% as.period())
)
```

output

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# ExtractionTime         PropertyTime       ClipTime  
# <Duration>             <Duration>         <Period>  
# 1 1009s (~16.82 minutes) 36013s (~10 hours) 10H 17M 2S
# 2 1010s (~16.83 minutes) 36013s (~10 hours) 10H 17M 3S
# 3 1011s (~16.85 minutes) 36013s (~10 hours) 10H 17M 4S
# 4 1012s (~16.87 minutes) 36013s (~10 hours) 10H 17M 5S
# 5 1013s (~16.88 minutes) 36013s (~10 hours) 10H 17M 6S
# 6 1014s (~16.9 minutes)  36013s (~10 hours) 10H 17M 7S
```

**Update 1**
OKAY. I didn't know the output had to be chr. So let's do it differently.

```
AddTime = function(t1, t2) {
  (t1 %>% hms() %>% as.duration()) + 
    (t2 %>% hms() %>% as.duration())
}

DurationToStr = function(t) {
  td = t %>% seconds_to_period
  sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', td@hour, minute(td), second(td))
}

df %>% mutate(
  ClipTime = AddTime(ExtractionTime, PropertyTime) %>% DurationToStr())
```

output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  ExtractionTime PropertyTime ClipTime
  <chr>          <chr>        <chr>   
1 00:16:49       10:00:13     10:17:02
2 00:16:50       10:00:13     10:17:03
3 00:16:51       10:00:13     10:17:04
4 00:16:52       10:00:13     10:17:05
5 00:16:53       10:00:13     10:17:06
6 00:16:54       10:00:13     10:17:07
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I need the output to be exactly as I listed above (HH:MM:SS) in each column and this solution changes the format of each column.

Comment: I added a program update.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use `lubridate` to automate some of this, but I have two functions I use for quick conversion into and out of `HH:MM:SS`:

```r
time2num <- function(x) {
  vapply(strsplit(x, ':'), function(y) sum(as.numeric(y) * c(60*60, 60, 1)),
         numeric(1), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
}
num2time <- function(x, digits.secs = getOption("digits.secs", 3)) {
  hr <- as.integer(x %/% 3600)
  min <- as.integer((x - 3600*hr) %/% 60)
  sec <- (x - 3600*hr - 60*min)
  if (anyNA(digits.secs)) {
    # a mostly-arbitrary determination of significant digits,
    # motivated by @Roland https://stackoverflow.com/a/27767973
    for (digits.secs in 1:6) {
      if (any(abs(signif(sec, digits.secs) - sec) > (10^(-3 - digits.secs)))) next
      digits.secs <- digits.secs - 1L
      break
    }
  }
  sec <- sprintf(paste0("%02.", digits.secs[[1]], "f"), sec)
  sec <- paste0(ifelse(grepl("^[0-9]\\.", sec), "0", ""), sec)
  out <- sprintf("%02i:%02i:%s", hr, min, sec)
  out[is.na(x)] <- NA_character_
  out
}
```

With that,

```r
num2time(sum(time2num(c("00:16:49", "10:00:13"))), 0)
# [1] "10:17:02"
```

`time2num` converts a colon-delimited time-like string into a number (it just multiplies the smallest-to-largest significant digits by 1, 60, and 3600),

```r
time2num(c("00:16:49", "10:00:13"))
# [1]  1009 36013
```

which can then be operated on as `numeric`, and then converted back to "HH:MM:SS" format.