# converting to hh:mm:ss format in r

Tags: r, lubridate, rscript

How would I convert seconds into h/m/s format. I've tried to use `seconds_to_period` but it only gives the value in seconds. e.g

```
ID   Time
1    345 secs
2    121 secs
3     78 secs
```

I want this is in HH:MM:SS format how is this done?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70843341/3358272; while that _question_ asks about the opposite direction, my answer provided functions for both directions.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `hms` from `hms` after converting to `period`

```
library(lubridate)
df1$Time <- hms::hms(seconds_to_period(readr::parse_number(df1$Time)))
```

-output

```
> df1
  ID     Time
1  1 00:05:45
2  2 00:02:01
3  3 00:01:18
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Time = c("345 secs", "121 secs", "78 secs"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I tried hms and It still gave me the same answer rather than giving it in the hms format

Comment: @b10 i get the hms format with the data.  Updated the output i got