# Convert character class to time object ignoring NAs R

Tags: r, lubridate

Whilst there are many similar threads related to my question, I cannot find one that actually addresses it. I have a data column of times, with some missing values:

```
t <- data.frame(time=c("NA", "NA", "11:10", "09:30", "NA", "10:50", "12:55", "08:05", "08:15", "NA", "NA"))
```

I would like to turn the column into a time variable, ignoring missing values?

Comment: To be clear, base R doesn't really have a "time" class, it has `Date` (just the date portion) and `POSIXt` (date and time-of-day). Some packages provide "time-of-day" classes (`data.table` as shown, as well as `lubridate`). If you're just looking to convert these strings (whether `HH:MM` or `MM:SS`, doesn't matter) to a number (whether or not it _prints_ like a time), you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/70843341/3358272 (there are other Q/As with similar intent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make use of [`asITime`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.8/topics/IDateTime) from `data.table` package:

```
t$time <- data.table::as.ITime(t$time)
> t
       time
1      <NA>
2      <NA>
3  11:10:00
4  09:30:00
5      <NA>
6  10:50:00
7  12:55:00
8  08:05:00
9  08:15:00
10     <NA>
11     <NA
```